# FormatException on a DataGridViewComboboxCell.Value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I have a problem which I can't figure out.

I have an DataGridViewComboboxCell,

```
List<ComboBoxItem> klanten = new List<ComboBoxItem>();
foreach (ICustomer customer in CustomerFactory.CreateCustomers())
{
     klanten.Add(new ComboBoxItem(customer.Naam, customer.Id));
}
klanten.Add(new ComboBoxItem("Klant aanvraag", -1));

uxInvoerenKlant.DataSource = klanten;
uxInvoerenKlant.DisplayMember = "Text";
uxInvoerenKlant.ValueMember = "Value";
```

When the option "Klant aanvraag" is selected the user gets a window where the user can choose another customer.
This is for the reason the user was not assigned for a specific project for that customer.
When the user chose one it will be changed in the Combobox with the following code.

```
uxUrenInvoeren[collumnIndex, row.Index].Value = uxInvoerenKlant.Items[klantIndex];
```

`klantindex` is the customer that needs to be selected, because it is retrieved from the combobox. It is the right kind of object in my opinion.

After this, the `datagridview_dataerror` event is raised where I get the Format exception with the following exception text.

> DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem myself.

The `uxUrenInvoeren[collumnIndex, row.Index].Value` contained the value of the ComboBoxItem and not the ComboBoxItem itself. The code now looks like this:

```
ComboBoxItem item = uxInvoerenKlant.Items[klantIndex] as ComboBoxItem;
if (item != null)
{
    uxUrenInvoeren[collumnIndex, row.Index].Value = item.Value;
}
```

In this way it goes well.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be your value of -1. Maybe you need to start with 0

Comment: you were almost right, the uxUrenInvoeren[collumnIndex, row.Index].Value was -1 but this was not the problem. i posted the way it is solved as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You should add the selected value to the items collection of the combobox, the exception is raised since the value assigned is not found in the `Item` collection of the `ComboBoxColumn` and hence not a valid value.

Try adding it using `Add`

```
(dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).Items.Add
```

Comment: uxInvoerenKlant is the name of dataGridView1.Columns[0]
as far as i know would that replace your:
(dataGridView1.Columns[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxColumn).

and i need the comboboxItem because i need text and value, for customerName and customerId

Comment: uxInvoerenKlant would replace 0 and i think you can do it as Add(new ComboBoxItem... . The values would be controlled on the basis of Text and Value, hope these are properties of ComboBoxItem

Answer (score -1):

Solution :

```
Private Sub gvPrint_DataError(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewDataErrorEventArgs) Handles gvPrint.DataError
    If e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Formatting Or e.Context = DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.PreferredSize Then
        e.ThrowException = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: The question used C#, please use C# in the answer.